# performSegueWithIdentifier Pausing App and Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

I have the following line in my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method for my `UICollectionView`:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetail", sender: self)
```

When the cell is tapped, the app pauses (you can't interact with the app at all), no error message is given, and the segue doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Show full code of your project view controller

Comment: are you sure the identifier matches the one in storyboard?

Comment: yes it does. unfortunately the project code is private. any particular part of the code you want to see?

Comment: Check if the delegate method is called on main thread using `[NSThread isMainThread]`. 

The situation I've encountered is different from this (mine is that the code in the delegate method get called but the UI updates after few seconds), but I think it's somehow related.